# wrong number after converting

Tags: java, android, parcel

I try to send position of array from my `MainActivity` to another Activity with this code:

Main Activity:

```
contactinfo.putExtra("position", String.valueOf(position));
```

I have a toast and that shows the right position I have clicked in this Activity.

Another Activity that gets the data:

```
position = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("position");
Toast.makeText(this,String.valueOf(position),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

This Toast always shows 0, even when I have click on position 1 or another one.

What's the problem with converting int to String or sending an int via Intents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are sending a `String`, but trying to retrieve an `int`.

You don't need to convert your integer to a String to pass it to the next Activity.

Change `contactinfo.putExtra("position", String.valueOf(position));` to `contactinfo.putExtra("position", position);`.

Answer (score 0):

In Main Activity Use :

```
contactinfo.putExtra("position" , position);
```

In Another Activity Use :

```
position=getIntent().getIntExtra("position", 0);
```

Comment: thanks but i cant understand why you write 0 in ("position", 0)?

Comment: Learn the API.  Read the javadoc.  getIntent().getIntExtra( name, defVal ).  defVal is the default value in case the name is not found in the extras.